# Laravel 5.2 JSON response sometime start with Zero

Tags: jquery, json, laravel-5

I have the following problem on laravel 5.2 Json response
as some time response start with 0 leading the json response which make me error in client side only with the user interaction 
JSON response

```
0{"message":"now shall be readed at least in javascript","fromuser":7,"fromShopid":null,"to_shop_id":9,"to_user_id":null,"status":0,"updated_at":"2016-11-16 14:20:45","created_at":"2016-11-16 14:20:45","id":58,"Created":1479295245,"shopName":"\u041a\u043e\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043b\u0438\u043a","shopLogo":"logo1475487308.jpg","shopUrl":"korablik","MyName":"Evgenia Kondrakhina","MyPhoto":"logo14717092787.jpg","ShopOwner":1}
```

this response happens sometimes not rarely for example it can happen after close browser and open it again or just happen without reason

Laravel side Code :

```
 public function sendmessageboxShop (Request $Request){

    $input= $Request->all();
    $me = \App\User::find(\Auth::user()->id);
    $shopid=$input['Toshop'];
    $shopforme=\App\shop::findOrFail($shopid);
    $hefallow = \App\favirotshop::where("shop_id",$shopforme->id)
                                ->where("user_id",$me->id)
                                ->firstOrFail();

             if(trim($input['mes'])){

                                $themessagee=      \App\shopChat::create([
                                         'message' => $input['mes'],
                                         'fromuser' => $me->id,
                                         'fromShopid' => null,
                                         'to_shop_id' => $shopforme->id,
                                         'to_user_id' => null,
                                         'status' => 0,

                                     ]);



                           $themessagee["Created"] =strtotime($themessagee->created_at);
                           $themessagee["shopName"]=$shopforme->name;
                           $themessagee["shopLogo"]=$shopforme->logo;
                           $themessagee["shopUrl"]=$shopforme->friendly_url;
                           $themessagee["MyName"]=$me->name;
                           $themessagee["MyPhoto"]=$me->photolink;
                           $themessagee["ShopOwner"]=$shopforme->foruser;



                              event(new ChatToNode($themessagee));
                          return  response()->json($themessagee);

                              }

}
```

Jquery Side Code :

```
ShopID= $('#forShop').val();

                     $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url : '/sendmessageboxShop',
                        dataType : "json",
                        data: {
                               Toshop: ShopID,
                               mes:mes
                        },
                        beforeSend: function () {

                        }
                    }).always(function() { // always executed

                    })
                       .fail(function(data) {
                        sweetAlert("Oops...", "there was erorr in connection", "error");
                           })
                       .done(function( $obj ) {


    if($obj)
         {  if($("div").find("[data-logforShop='" + ShopID + "']").is(":visible")){


                            $('#chat-messages').append('<div class="message right">'+
                              '<img src="/profilepics/'+$obj.MyPhoto+'" />'+
                                '<div class="bubble">'+
                              $obj.message  +
                                  '<div class="corner"></div>'+
                                    '<span id="timeagodiv" class="modaltime" data-livestamp="'+$obj.created_at+'"></span>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>');


                            var bottomCoord = $('#chat-messages')[0].scrollHeight;
                            $('#chat-messages').slimScroll({scrollTo: bottomCoord});
                            $("#messageval").val('');

                         }
                         else {

                           console.log("no");
                         }
}
                        });
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a laravel user, but in case the problem is from laravel core, you can fix in your javascript by adding a data filter to the request.

```
ShopID = $('#forShop').val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/sendmessageboxShop',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        Toshop: ShopID,
        mes: mes
    },dataFilter: function(raw_json){
        return raw_json.replace(/[0-9]+\{/, "{");
    }
})
....the rest of your code
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for this answer absolutely this will work fine but i don't think its the solution for laravel Core i will mark as correct answer while i hope to have answer for laravel !

Comment: In that case, you should create a middleware in laravel that will format the output buffer before it gets displayed to the screen